# How to implement a loop to read the array of names that checks for number of upper case letters etc?

Tags: c, string, loops, character-arrays

The program as is is telling me there are 0 upper case 0 lower case 0 spaces and 0 tabs but 61 other characters for an array with 2 names that are lowercase. The names have 10 letters combined. I think I need a loop to iterate over the array but I'm not sure if that's correct or how I would do this.

```
for (i=0; i<n_names; i++){
    printf("%d: [[%s]]\n", i, names[i]);}
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    gets(names[i]);

    while (s[i] != 0)
    {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') {
            lowercase++;
            i++;
        }         
        else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') {
            uppercase++;
            i++;
        }                
        else if (s[i] == '  ') {         /* Tab - write '\t' for clarity! */
            tab++;
            i++;
        }
        else if (*names[i] == ' ') {
            spaces++;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            other++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

printf("Your string has %d lowercase letter(s) \n",lowercase);
printf("Your string has %d uppercase letter(s) \n",uppercase);
printf("Your string has %d tab(s) \n",tab);
printf("Your string has %d space(s) \n", spaces);
printf("Your string has %d other character(s) \n",other);
```

Comment: what is `*names[i] == ' '`?

Comment: on a side not i need to save the number of characters of each type for each word so that I can create a bill based on these characteristics.

Comment: names[i] is a character array where the names are stored after the user inputs them from stdin. (enum { MAX_CARDS = 20 };
 enum { MAX_NAME_LEN = 50 };
 char names[MAX_CARDS][MAX_NAME_LEN];
 int  n_names = 0;)(strcpy(names[n_names++], word);)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to set `i` back to 0 before your while loop.  So it's going to start at index 20 of `s`, whatever that is.  It's probably looking past the end of something, into some random memory location containing garbage.  Is `s` somehow related to `names`, or are they the same and the code just got messed up when you copied it into your question?

Comment: s should be names. sorry i did that part of the program in another file to begin with to see how it worked.

Comment: on a random side note, is there a reason that when i put names[i] in place of s[i] i have to make it *names[i]?

Comment: the reason is, `names[i]` is a string whereas `s[i]` is a character.

Comment: Please forget that the function `gets()` ever existed.  Pretend it is equivalent to calling `abort()`.  It is lethal; it cannot be used safely.  It should not be used even in test code.  And stop putting the close brace after the semi-colon of a statement; that is ***NOT*** where it goes — _ever_!  (And I mentioned that to you yesterday.)

Comment: i know. that's where we were told to put it in class and he takes points off for not following his syntax. I agree it's hard to follow. Nine times out of 10 that's where I get lost in my code and everything falls apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i, n_idx;
for (n_idx = 0; n_idx < n_names; n_idx++) {
    const char *s = names[n_idx];
    for (i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++) {   
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') {
            lowercase++;
        }    
        else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') {
            uppercase++;
        }    
        else if (s[i] == '\t') {    
            tab++;
        }   
        else if (s[i] == ' ') {
            spaces++;
        }   
        else{
            other++;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you pasted the entire code, I presume you "s" points to strings in names. Also initialize "i" to zero before your while loop.

Please use standard functions islower, isupper and 
for tab you need to **compare with '\t'**

Other useful functions in ctype.h for your scenario.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int isalnum(int c);
int isalpha(int c);
int isascii(int c);
int isblank(int c);
int iscntrl(int c);
int isdigit(int c);
int isgraph(int c);
int islower(int c);
int isprint(int c);
int ispunct(int c);
int isspace(int c);
int isupper(int c);
int isxdigit(int c);
```